# On the Basics of the Definition of a Function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

There are two sentences in the chapter titled, "Preliminaries" in the book *Calculus, A Complete Course* by Adams, which I find confusing. The first one:

> "The domain and range of a mathematical function can be any sets of objects; they do not have to consist of numbers."

How can a **mathematical function** have a domain other than numbers? In order to feed something into a mathematical function, we will have to translate it ultimately somehow into a number. I can think of a function which has letters as its input and output. For example, a function which receives a letter and returns another letter which are somehow related. Can this be an example? If yes, how does it establish the *rule* between the quantities? After all, we have a mathematical function.

The other sentence is

> "A **function** $f$ on a set $D$ into a set $S$ is a rule that assigns a *unique* element $f(x)$ in $S$ to each element $x$ in $D$. In this definition $D=D(f)$ (read “$D$ of $f$”) is the domain of the function $f$. The range $R=R(f)$ of $f$ is the subset of $S$ consisting of all *values* $f(x)$ of the function."

Why is in the case of the range, the word "subset" used? I understand that $S$ is the set of all the output values. Therefore, it is the range of the function. Why do we need the word "subset" here?

Comment: If I have some presents I want to give my family, I might have a function which when I decide who is going to get each present.  (Each particular present goes to one individual.)  So the domain is the set of presents and the co-domain could be the set of possible recipients and the range the people get at least one present.   If nobody gets more than one present, this is an injective 1-1 function; if everybody gets at least one present then it is a surjective function

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is a function then its domain is $X$, its codomain is $Y$ and its range is $\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}\subseteq Y$. The range can be a *proper* subset of $Y$.

Comment: A function that produce for every *expression* of a formal language its [length](https://realpython.com/len-python-function/#:~:text=The%20function%20len()%20is,with%20many%20different%20data%20types.) has a number as output but a non-number as input.

Comment: And consider the function "father of x": its domain is the set of humans (every human has a father) but its range is a subset of the set of humans (not every human has a son).

Comment: “In order to feed something into a mathematical function we will have to translate it ultimately somehow into a number”. This is not true. Why do you think this?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I am thinking of programming where any piece of information, a letter for instance, is translated into the binary system.

Comment: Functions in maths are *related* to programming functions in the sense that each input has a single output. But in mathematics, the inputs and outputs can be any objects. In practice, in mathematics, our inputs/outputs are usually numbers or other mathematical objects like rings, fields, sequences, etc. So it is quite common for inputs and outputs of mathematical functions to not just be numbers, but other objects.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is a function whose domain is a certain set of *ordered pairs of matrices* and range consists of matrices. Differentiation of polynomials (restricting to polynomials for simplicity) is a function from polynomials to polynomials. Horizontal translation of graphs in precalculus is a function whose domain consists of ordered pairs, one entry being a subset of the plane (or restrict to graphs of functions, or something else if you wish) and the other entry being a real number, and whose range consists of subsets of the plane.